# java shell script question

Tags: java

I am developing a license Generation tool in java.I required to call a shell script from my java program which is license generation tool and after that I have to send command to license generation tool which takes a xml as a input but I am unable to do it please help me

Comment: What have you already have? What is the exact problem?

Comment: I can execute only ./LicenseGen.sh command but I want to execute one more command under ./LicenseGen.sh plz help me

Answer (score 2):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("here_you_add_your_shell_commands");
```

- [API Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Comment: but it work only for one command and I want to pass next command also

Comment: You can execute it again with different arg. or create a shell script and invoke it.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ProcessBuilder prBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(your_script/command, arg1, arg2);
prBuilder = prBuilder.directory(your_working_dir);
Process p = prBuilder.start();
```

Comment: I can execute only ./LicenseGen.sh command but I want to execute one more command under ./LicenseGen.sh plz help me

Comment: Does LicenseGen.sh starts its own shell?(like `license#`)