# to run shell script through java

Tags: java, shell

I want to run a shell script through java .I am using license generation tool,It can be call with the help of ./LicenseGen.sh command,under it I require to execute another command 
create licensekey -x license-input.xml
which create a new licensekey.xml file where license-input.xml is a input file and licensekey is a output xml file how it is posssible in java please help me.

my code is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ProcessExample {

/**
 * @param args
 */
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

       File file=new File("/opt");
      // List<String> list=new List<String>();
       ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("./LicenseGen.sh");
       processBuilder.directory(file);

        Process process=processBuilder.start();      
       //processBuilder.command("create licensekey -x license-input.xml");
       //process=processBuilder.start();
       InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

       String line;

       System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", 
          Arrays.toString(args));

       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
       }

     }
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't ask new question for the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831265/java-shell-script-question

Answer (score 6):

You can't execute the script directly since it has to be interpreted by a shell like bash. 
Note that bash is an executeable.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "/path/LicenseGen.sh");
```

Comment: step 1:./LicenseGen.sh step 2:create licensekey -x license-input.xml

Comment: @Nilesh I think you're better off to write and run a script which does both steps.

Answer (score 0):

Use commons cli http://commons.apache.org/cli/
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have used `JSch` extensively for remote login and script executions. I used `google Expect4j` with `Jsch` for executing scripts on remote machines in expect mode(send/wait). Since, you have to execute command one after another, you can try this.

It can also be used for local execution that you require. `The only worry is that you need to login (into your local machine) for execution.`

For jsch, go to http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/
For Expect4j, go to http://code.google.com/p/expect4j/

Thanks.